# vite-node: Run code located in server directory

Tags: typescript, vite, vitest

I want to use vite-node to run some database migrations which I have in `$lib/server/migrate.ts`.

When I try to `npx vite-node src/lib/server/migrate`, I get this error:

```
Error: Cannot import $lib/server/migrate.ts into client-side code
```

I am running this script on the server only. How do I get this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why, but **adding the .ts extension** to the filename got it to run without any complaints:

```bash
npx vite-node src/lib/server/migrate.ts
```